# How good an approximation to the derivative is an arc-length based approximation?

Tags: derivatives, approximation

*Note - my original definition below was wrong. I hope this replacement is better.*

The usual approximation to
$f'(x)$
with step size $h$
is
$D_h(f, x)
= \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$.
This has
so many nice properties
that I will not state any of them
except that
$D_h(f, x)
= f'(x) + \Theta(h)
$
as $h \to 0$.

A better approximation is
$D^{=}_h(f, x)
= \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
$
which satisfies
$D^{=}_h(f, x)
= f'(x) + \Theta(h^2)
$
as $h \to 0$.

These depend on 
the orientation of 
the coordinate system.
In trying to come up
with a rotation-independent
derivative,
it occurred to me
that the arc length
is the obvious choice
for rotation independence.
So here is my definition:

*(These next two paragraphs have been
completely rewritten.)*

Let $(x(t), y(t))$
be a parameterization of $f$.
The simplest one is
$x(t) = t, y(t) = f(t)$,
but any will work.
For example,
for a circle,
two possibilities are
$(t, \sqrt{1-t^2})$
and
$(\cos(t), \sin(t))$
(for different ranges of $t$).

I define
$D^{s}_h(f,t)
= \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}
= \frac{y(t+a(f, t, h))-y(t)}{x(t+a(f, t, h))-x(t)}
$
where
$a(f, t, h)$
is such that
the arc length of $f$
from $t$ to
$t+a(f, t, h)$
is $h$.
In otherwords,
$\int_t^{t+a(f, t, h)}
\sqrt{x'^2(u)+y'^2(u)}du
=h
$.

My general question,
which I an too lazy and tired
at the moment
to attempt to solve,
is
what are the properties of
$D^{s}_h(f,x)$?
Is there a nice expansion of
$D^{s}_h(f,x)$
in powers of $h$
with the coefficients 
being functions of $f$
and its derivatives?
Is this of any real use?
Is this actually easy to solve,
so it is one of those problems
which,
as Littlewood said,
"there is less to this than meets the eye"?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: How do the expressions 'depend on the orientation of the coordinate system'?

Comment: If, say, $|f'(x)| \le 1$, the graph of $f$ can be rotated by up to $\pi/4$ and still remain a function. If $f'(a) > 0$ for some $a$, after the graph of $f$ has been rotated, the slope of $f$ at the point whose $x$-coordinate used to be $a$ will have been increased. However, the arc-length derivative will not have its value changed.

Comment: Should the denominator be $a(f,x,h)$ rather than $h$?  Otherwise $D_h^s(f,x)$ might not approach $f'(x)$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Yeah, my definition is wrong. I am working on a revision which, I hope, will have a better chance of being reasonable.